# how to get json key value in php?

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach, key

How do I get all of the keys value in this JSON with PHP?
my php code is:

```
<?php 
$json = json_decode('{
    "data": {
        "after": [{
            "google.com": "35"
        }, {
            "yahoo.com": "10"
        }, {
            "worldi.ir": "30"
        }, {
            "cnn.com": "554"
        }, {
            "scio.ir": "887"
        }],
        "before": [{
            "bbc.com": "44"
        }, {
            "rtl.com": "15"
        }, {
            "quran.com": "9"
        }, {
            "lap.com": "12"
        }, {
            "search.com": "13"
        }]
    }
}');
foreach($json->data->after as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key<br/>";
    foreach(((array)$json->data->after)[$key] as $val) {
        echo "$val<br/>";
    }
}
?>
```

results

```
0
35
1
10
2
30
3
554
4
887
```

don't show key value. i want get all key value.such as google.com, yahoo.com, worldi.ir cnn.com, and ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`after` is an array, so the `$key` returned in the outer foreach loop is just an index (an integer). You should include `$key => $value` again in your second foreach to get the key of each inner object. Further, you can just use a foreach on the `$value` of your first foreach. You don't have to specify the whole key path down to it again.

```
<?php 
$json = json_decode('{
    "data": {
        "after": [{
            "google.com": "35"
        }, {
            "yahoo.com": "10"
        }, {
            "worldi.ir": "30"
        }, {
            "cnn.com": "554"
        }, {
            "scio.ir": "887"
        }],
        "before": [{
            "bbc.com": "44"
        }, {
            "rtl.com": "15"
        }, {
            "quran.com": "9"
        }, {
            "lap.com": "12"
        }, {
            "search.com": "13"
        }]
    }
}');
foreach($json->data->after as $key => $value) {
    foreach($value as $k => $val) {
        echo "$k<br/>$val<br/>";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this solution:**

```
<?php
    $json = json_decode('{
        "data": {
            "after": [{
                "google.com": "35"
            }, {
                "yahoo.com": "10"
            }, {
                "worldi.ir": "30"
            }, {
                "cnn.com": "554"
            }, {
                "scio.ir": "887"
            }],
            "before": [{
                "bbc.com": "44"
            }, {
                "rtl.com": "15"
            }, {
                "quran.com": "9"
            }, {
                "lap.com": "12"
            }, {
                "search.com": "13"
            }]
        }
    }');


    foreach($json->data->after as $key => $value) {

        echo key($json->data->after[$key]);
        
        foreach(((array)$json->data->after)[$key] as $val) {
            echo "$val<br/>";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php 
$json = json_decode('{
    "data": {
        "after": [{
            "google.com": "35"
        }, {
            "yahoo.com": "10"
        }, {
            "worldi.ir": "30"
        }, {
            "cnn.com": "554"
        }, {
            "scio.ir": "887"
        }],
        "before": [{
            "bbc.com": "44"
        }, {
            "rtl.com": "15"
        }, {
            "quran.com": "9"
        }, {
            "lap.com": "12"
        }, {
            "search.com": "13"
        }]
    }
}');
foreach($json->data as $key1 => $value1) {
    echo "$key1: \n";
    foreach($value1 as $key2 => $value2) {
         echo "$key2 -> ";
         foreach($value2 as $key3 => $value3) {
             echo "$key3 -> $value3\n";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Output:

```
after: 
0 -> google.com -> 35
1 -> yahoo.com -> 10
2 -> worldi.ir -> 30
3 -> cnn.com -> 554
4 -> scio.ir -> 887
before: 
0 -> bbc.com -> 44
1 -> rtl.com -> 15
2 -> quran.com -> 9
3 -> lap.com -> 12
4 -> search.com -> 13
```